# LINQ left join object reference not set

Tags: vb.net, linq, left-join

I'm trying to left join two tables:

```
Dim ausartpreise = From ausart In wpneu.Dataset.Tables(1).AsEnumerable
                   Group Join wp In wpneu.Dataset.Tables(0).AsEnumerable On ausart.Item(2) Equals wp.Item(0) _
                   And ausart.Item(3) Equals wp.Item(2)
                   Into joined_res = Group From joinedrow In joined_res.DefaultIfEmpty _
                   Select New With {.artnr = ausart.Item(0), .lfdnrkal = ausart.Item(1), .artnrhz = ausart.Item(2), .lfdnr1 = ausart.Item(3), _
                                    .menge = ausart.Item(4), .m = ausart.Item(5), .wpneu = IIf(joinedrow Is Nothing, 0, joinedrow.Item(72))}
```

As you see, I catch, if there are no matches. But despite of that, I get an 'object reference not set' error on `joinedrow`.

Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `If(joinedrow Is Nothing, 0, joinedrow.Item(72))` instead of `IIf`

`IIF` is not short circuited and will evaluate both the true and false parts no matter what `joinedrow Is Nothing` evaluates to. Even though it will only use one of the results. `IF(...)` was introduced later in vb.net that will only evalute the needed expression.